# Is it possible to implement mathematical deduce in semantic web?

Tags: semantic-web, reasoning, swrl

**For example:**  we have premises `a < b` and `b < c`, can you deduce `a < c` in Semanric web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a reasoner and by considering `a`, `b` and `c` as OWL classes (which are kind of equivalent to sets from set theory) you could do it.

For example the following ontology represent your premises:

```
Class: a
  SubClassOf: b

Class: b
  SubClassOf: c

Class: c
```

Now if you were to query for the subclasses (direct and indirect) of `c` you would retrieve `a` and `b`, showing that `a` is a subclass (`⊂`) of `c` without explicit assertion.

Note that you could also use the Semantic Web Rule Language if you want to infer information based on the values of `a`, `b` and `c`. You could look at `swrlb:greaterThan` or `swrlb:smallerThan` for that.

Comment: Do you have any example that use SWRL in protege? I can not find an excutable example from the internet that uses the math biult-ins of SWRL.